# python list with different type to array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a problem about list to array conversion. I have a list from a csv file, like

`a=[['1','a'],['2','b']]`

Now I only want the first column, the number '1' and '2', and convert them to a numpy array. How do I accomplish this? Using `b = np.array(a)` put all items as string into the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). Note a standard NumPy array is not a good choice for mixed types (dtype `object`), as this will cause all data to be stored in pointers.

```
a = [['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b']]

from operator import itemgetter

res = np.fromiter(map(itemgetter(0), a), dtype=int)

print(res)

array([1, 2])
```

Some performance benchmarking:

```
a = [['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b']] * 10000

%timeit np.fromiter(map(itemgetter(0), a), dtype=int)  # 4.31 ms per loop
%timeit np.array(a)[:, 0].astype(int)                  # 15.1 ms per loop
%timeit np.array([i[0] for i in a]).astype(int)        # 8.3 ms per loop
```

If you need a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) of mixed types:

```
x = np.array([(int(i[0]), i[1]) for i in a],
             dtype=[('val', 'i4'), ('text', 'S10')])

print(x)

array([(1, b'a'), (2, b'b')], 
      dtype=[('val', '<i4'), ('text', 'S10')])
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an elegant solution. But what if I do not know which column is number? I have a very big list and I do not want to check which row is number. I simply want the code to select the number from string. How do I do this?

Comment: In each row, will be same column be a number? Choosing *which column* to convert is likely beyond the scope of your question. I'd advise you [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with *exactly* the scenario you want to handle.

Comment: Yes, one column has a certain type, for example all number in the first column and all string in the 10th column. I want to choose which row is number and which row is string and then convert all number row to an array. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ZhaoHao, You shouldn't change your question. This may seem harsh, but there are already 4 answers. All of them will have to be updated or deleted. Some people may be asleep by now, depending on their time zone and miss this completely. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You'd first need to create a new list`, that only contains the first values of the lists in a. For example

```
c = []
for row in a:
    c.append(row[0])
b = np.array(c)
```

More Pythonic would probably be a list comprehension:

```
c = [x[0] for x in a]
b = np.array(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = [['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b']]
print(np.array(a)[:, 0].astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a=array([int(i[0]) for i in a])
```